# How to add social follow button to header?

Tags: headers, social-sharing

I'm using the theme "Awaken" and I need to add social follow button on the right side of the logo, just above the search box. Please see my [website here](http://znerim.com/). I have included the social button in the footer section with the help of widgets but is not available for header. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to:

- Create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so you can still update the base theme
- Modify `header.php` or whatever outputs the logo to output your button
- Add custom CSS to style/position your button (in the child theme obviously)